# TeamCity build triggered by Spring config changes?

Tags: java, spring, maven, build, teamcity

Our process currently detects any commit to the repo and triggers a TC build using Maven, and that includes Spring configuration files. To me it sounds silly to have to recompile all the Java source code just for a Spring config change, where a recompilation is not required. Anyone has any experience in working around this?

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid triggering after changes in some files using [VCS Trigger Rules](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-buildTriggerRules). For example edit `VCS Trigger` as on screenshot below:

[image]